# Is that possible to send and retrieve message to queue or topic using Azure resource manager API

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

I am a beginner in Azure and using PHP and Azure Manager or Service REST API passing a message to queue or subscriber.

I am able to send and receive messages using a service API (servicebus.windows.net).

is that way to send and receive messages using Azure Manager API(Management.azure.com)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no way, with the management API you can do certain operations such as deleting the namespace, authorization rules, entities,etc.
Sending and Receiving messages are data operations that can only be done via the Service API.

Comment: thanks @jdresc, can we send a message through the ARM template?

Comment: @Shesh no, you cannot send messages through the ARM template, I am curious to know why you would need that ? the purpose of Service Bus is to have async communication by sending messages from Applications using the SB sdk and receiving from other applications, with ARM templates you can automate the Service Bus deployment if needed, but only that.

Comment: thanks for your answer, one of my clients want to send a message using management API only, they said we can not go longer to using service API because these API expiring soon, but I can't see that kind of notification in docs. as I know only classic API will be expiring soon.

Comment: I think your client is confused, what is expiring soon is the classic API (RDFE) which is utilized for management operations only, hence if they are using it indeed they should migrate to ARM APIs, but this has nothing to do with the service APIs such as sending or receiving messages.
Take a look at this article https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/messaging-on-azure/deprecating-service-management-support-for-azure-service-bus/ba-p/370909